# Cycles doesn't render light in viewport

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I can see lights when I hit  <kbd>F12</kbd> and through the camera, but in viewport everything is blank, without light.

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

Comment: You using an AMD GPU by any chance? If so, check your drivers.

Comment: I use geforce rtx with the newest drivers